# How to remove bootstraps mobile first (use desktop first)

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

Is it possible to remove mobile first approach in bootstrap and use regular desktop first? Basically from desktop to tablet to mobile, as it used to be.

I want to keep the responsive features, but when creating media queries to target smaller devices, I want to go from desktop > tablet > mobile. Do I need to edit some files?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to achieve? Bootstrap still works very well on larger screens by default, so I'm wondering what your exact concerns are?

Comment: If you want to remove the Responsive (RWD) approach altogether, they provide instructions for that: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

Comment: @settheline Well yeah it works, but often the media queries are overwriting my own media queries and I often have to use !important or other stuff and it just doesnt feel very clean. I dont understand why is it forced to actually build your site from mobile up. Because the default media queries are also from mobile up. Should I use some different ones to maybe better fit my needs?

Comment: @cvrebert No I dont want to remove the responsive features, as I stated in my question.

Comment: Are you talking about the grid system? I'm not aware of other components of Bootstrap besides the grid that are affected by media queries out of the box.

Comment: actually no, the problem is that I use media queries like max-width, instead of defaults min-width.. so some styles from lets say @max-width of 767px are going to be applied to 480px too..

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap was completely built in that 'mobile first' mindset.. It wouldn't be a simple thing to make changes on that scale. If you want to use desktop first, as it used to be, I would recommend just using the older versions of bootstrap.

You can find Bootstrap 2 here:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

If I'm not mistaken, that one uses the desktop first approach.

Comment: Yeah bootstrap 2 takes ont he approach of desktop first and I suppose is a better solution to change the version of bootsrap that you are using rather than altering bootstrap 3 to meet your needs

Comment: Bootstrap v2.3.2 has several known bugs and is no longer maintained.

Comment: @Blake Mann Yea I was worried it was just way too deep in the core. But I prefer using the newer version rather than the archive one. I also like the new grid system. Maybe if it would be possible to just use the grid system from bootstrap, I wouldnt even need all the extra features.

Comment: I personally use the latest version of bootstrap, but make all my queries from a desktop down standpoint, without too many issues. Perhaps there are other optimizations you could perform to your CSS that would help with this? It may just be a matter of organizing things a bit better to try to prevent style conflicts. Unfortunately, thats not quite so easy to give you any advice on, without taking a pretty in-depth look at your code.

Comment: yeah i guess you are right, the problem might be that I use media queries like max-width, instead of defaults min-width.. so some styles from lets say @max-width of 767px are going to be applied to 480px too. Do you order you media queries like this? max-width: 1200px then max-width: 991px etc.?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I do. Sometimes if I know that I've got a large set of styles that only apply to a larger screen size, I'll mix in a few min-width media queries as well. You aren't really tied down to using any particular method of desktop first or mobile first. You can kind of hybridize it based on your needs

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I would use the terms Desktop first, or mobile first, as IMHO they are not really representative of what bootstrap is.

Bootstrap 2.3.2 (as to what has been mentioned as Desktop first) did not have responsive features built in, you had to 'turn them on' by including an additional CSS file (bootstrap-responsive.cs I do believe).
I wouldn't have called this Desktop first, simply that the base CSS had limited flexibility for different screen sizes.

They changed that paradigm in Bootstrap 3, now you do not need to include an additional CSS file for the responsive features, it is all included So I wouldn't call this a Mobile first approach, but an approach that is flexible for different screen sizes, regardless of the device, weather it be Desktop Tablet, Mobile, Projector, etc, I would say more its more device agnostic approach.

Now you say you still want the responsive features (so reverting to Bootstrap 2 without the responsive CSS you would lose the responsive), so is there something specific you seem to be concerned about with Bootstrap 3 that would somehow be of hindrance?

Ultimately the CSS simply rendered based on the screen size, I wouldn't call it a Mobile First, Then Desktop then Tablet approach at all, simply responsive to the screen size.

Comment: Please see my comment above. Basically they advise and force you to building your website first for mobile devices with less content, and then expanding the content and what the user sees, when they are using bigger screens. The media queries are built that way and when trying to use custom media queries but first for desktops and then for mobiles, the desktop styles are overwriting the declared mobile styles and therefor I have to use !important to fix it.

Comment: Without specific examples, having to use !important to me simply means that you CSS rule is not as specific as a preceding one. I have used bootstrap 3 many times, primarily for desktop sites and never had any issues, although as with any library it has an opinion, and working with it tends to make life easier than butting heads with it. I find that media queries have to be written in a certain order to work properly, primarily because of the cascading nature of CSS anyway.

Comment: yeah I think thats the problem, that I use media queries like max-width, instead of defaults min-width.. so some styles from lets say @max-width of 767px are going to be applied to 480px too.